# What's the best why to do a local high scores board in my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos

I'm trying to make a **local** high scores board for my app, but with no success till now.
I searched anywhere for a **local** high score board code but didn't found any.
What is the best why to write such a thing?

If you can please post example code.

Thanks.

Comment: You should clarify what exactly your problem is, with the GUI or with holding the data, ... SO is for helping with specific problems, not for writing your code for you.

Answer (score 2):

A very easy way, assuming the data set is small, would be to store an NSArray in the NSUserDefaults.

If the data set is larger you could use CoreData or even just a file created with an NSKeyedArchiver.

Answer (score 0):

A sorted array of structures, persistent on disk?

Comment: I dont know how to do it. Please give a code example or a explanation.

Thanks again.

Comment: Read up on the NSMutableArray class: http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html .  You'll want to place your scores in something like that, then use one of the -sortUsing... methods to sort from high to low.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to use [this post](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/mac-os-x-development/15243-nsfilehandle-issue-creating-file.html#post69650) for starting off with file handling to make your data persistent.