# Local high scores code for iPhone

Tags: iphone, user-interface, uitableview, uiview

Does anyone have/know about a "local high scores" function for the iPhone?  I know about the various *global* high score frameworks, but I want something more personal and modest--just for the user/users of the iPhone.

I'm thinking something like: 
`-(UIView*)highScoresForLevel:(unsigned)levelNumber user:(NSString*)userName: score:(unsigned)newScore;`

you feed in the current level, user name, and score.  It looks up the top 10 in `NSUserDefaults` (or similar), updates with `userName,newScore` if necessary, then returns a `UIView` displaying the scores.

I ask because I figure this must have been done before a couple of million times.

I'm aware of the similar (but less specific) SO questions such as: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440223/best-way-to-display-a-high-scores-results), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1896031/whats-the-best-why-to-do-a-local-high-scores-board-in-my-app) --which were not useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your custom class with the following class for encoding.

```
@interface HighScoreClass : NSObject 
{
    NSString * userName;
    NSInteger score;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString * userName;
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger score;
@end


@implementation HighScoreClass
@synthesize userName;
@synthesize score;

//To encode custom object
- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder
{
    [coder encodeObject:userName forKey:@"userName"];
    [coder encodeInteger:score forKey:@"score"];
}

//to decode your custom object
- (id) initWithCoder: (NSCoder *)coder
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.userName = [coder decodeObjectForKey:@"userName"];
        self.score = [coder decodeIntegerForKey:@"score"];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
    [userName release];
}
@end

//To store in NSUserDefaults an array "objectArray" of HighScoreClass objects
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:objectArray] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat@"highScoresForLevel%i",level];


//To retrieve from NSUserDefaults
NSUserDefaults *currentDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSData *highScoreArraySavedArray = [currentDefaults objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat@"highScoresForLevel%i",level]];
if (highScoreArraySavedArray != nil)
{
    NSArray *oldSavedArray = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:highScoreArraySavedArray];
    if (oldSavedArray != nil)
        objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:oldSavedArray];
    else
        objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
}
```

Then you just need to traverse the retrieved array and sort according to your requirement and display.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for that.  Looks interesting. In `encodeWithCoder` I guess you mean `userName,level,score`, rather than `label,numberID,numberID` !? I'm not sure how `objectArray` gets involved.  Is it an array of `HighScoreClass` objects?

Comment: I think I get this--I would need another Class: `@interface HighScoreView:UIView` which has an `objectArray` of `HighScoreClass`es--still heaps of work to do, but getting there...:-)

Comment: @iPadDeveloper2011 HighScoreClass is the base class to store information of user/level/score. create instance of that and store in the array. like HighScoreClass *objHighScoreClass = [[HighScoreClass alloc] init]; objHighScoreClass.userName = @""; like that. Add this objects in NSArray for multiple user.

Comment: Thanks @Jennis.  Wasn't a complete solution, but put me on the right track.  I've added some edits to make your answer more in line with my final solution.  I have a `HighScoreDisplay` class that uses something very like this `highScore` class.